# How do I stop the Find dialog from creating a pop-up when it can't find any text?

Tags: notepad++

I recently switched computers, and found that a pop-up appears if find can't find any matches:

Notepad ++ 6.3
[image]

In previous versions, it will only show up as a status bar:

Notepad++ 6.7.7
[image]

How do I revert it back to showing error messages in the status bar?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to state the version you are using.

Comment: Updated, and realized what the problem was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[*Answer by the OP:*](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/32746136/3)

I checked the versions, and it looks like I was using an older version on the new computer.